# Input alignement

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

```
     &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
      <section class="newsletter text-white text-center">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xl-9 mx-auto">
                <h2 class="mb-4">Iscriviti alla nostra newsletter</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-8 col-xl-7 mx-auto">
                <form>
                  <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-9 mb-2 mb-md-0">
                      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
                    </div>  
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
```

The code above displays this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RR0H7.png

If i wanted to put the button right next to the input, how'd i have to do it?

Comment: Change first col-12 to col-md-9 and the second col-12 to col-md-3

Answer (score 0):

```html
 <form action="">
       
   
       
       <input type="text"><span><button>submit</button></span>
    </form>
    
        //use span tag in html or in css display :inline-block
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
     &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
      <section class="newsletter text-white text-center">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xl-9 mx-auto">
                <h2 class="mb-4">Iscriviti alla nostra newsletter</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-8 col-xl-7 mx-auto">
                <form>
                  <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-9 mb-2 mb-md-0">
                      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
                      <span><button>submit</button></span>
                    </div>  
                    
                      
                
                  </div>
                </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work
You have set col into 12

I have distributed space as 9 + 3 across 12

```
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col-9 col-md-9 mb-2 mb-md-0">
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
                </div>  
                <div class="col-3 col-md-3">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </div>
              </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
  <section class="newsletter text-white text-center">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-9 mx-auto">
            <h2 class="mb-4">Iscriviti alla nostra newsletter</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-8 col-xl-7 mx-auto">
            <form>
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col-12 col-md-9 mb-2 mb-md-0">
                  <div class="d-flex">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                  </div>
                  
                </div>  
              </div>
            </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```